# jquery .remove performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to remove the li's with conditon under Ul in multiple div's.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="sel">.....</li>
        <li class="sel">.....</li>
         ............
        <li>.....</li>
        <li>.....</li>
         ...........
         <!-- I have some 600 li's -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have 200 li's with `class='sel'`. Now I need to remove the remaining 400 li's.

I am trying to remove in two ways, like,

```
$("ul", this).each(function(){
    $("li", this).each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        //Also tried with -- $(this).empty().remove();
    });
});
```

other way like,

```
$("ul", this).each(function(){
    $("li[class!=sel]", this).remove(); // Also tried with 'not'
});
```

Now the problem is, When I am trying to execute these ways In IE getting Script overloaded error.

Please help me out on other ways to remove unwanted li's.

Note: I don't want to keep the un-wanted li's to hide() state.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the [Attribute Not Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/), you don't need to wrap it with `.each()` - simply call it like this:

```
$('li[class!="sel"]').remove();
```

The selector (`'li[class!="sel"]'`) is grabbing all `<li>` elements that don't have class `sel` and then calling the `remove()` method on that entire set of elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxGhn/)

**Edit**

If you only want to target the `<ul>` which contains the `<li class="sel"></li>` elements, you can set the context like this:

```
// Find the first <li> with class="sel" and get it's parent <ul>
var $ul = $('li.sel:first').parent('ul');

// Use $ul as the context for the removal of the <li> elements
$('li[class!="sel"]', $ul).remove();
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I tried as I shown in second example in my question. :)

Comment: I should not disturb the li's in other ul's. So referred this.

Comment: @Max: I don't think `this` is referring to what you think it does in the context above. If you need to specify a context, you can simply add it to the selector. Perhaps being more specific about your current markup would help my clarify.

Comment: My application is with handling filters as we see in eBay. My selected filters should be highlighted under each category. When in one category if I select a field the remaining can be removed under that category.

Comment: @Max: I updated my answer to include an example of setting the context of your selector, so as to only select the `<ul>` which contains `<li class="sel">`

Comment: sorry to say, Still I am getting "Stop running the Script" error

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I ran into a similar problem just a couple of weeks ago, only in IE8, **even calling .remove() on a single item selected by id.** The problem only occurred when the element contained a great deal of content.

What I did was to call `.html('')` to clear the element just before calling `.remove()`. This reduced the time dramatically (sub-second).

**Mine was obviously a different situation** (one element vs. many, selected by id vs. contextual selectors, not sure what your `li` content is, etc.), **but it might be worth a shot**.

```
$("ul", this).each(function(){
    $("li[class!=sel]", this).html('').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try detaching the ul, remove the li's, then reattach the ul.

```
$("ul", this).detach().find("li").not(".sel").remove().end().end().appendTo(this);
```

This prevents the browser from redrawing until all li's that need to be removed are removed.

Comment: How come he is passing in `this` with his selector?

Comment: @mrtsherman He is looping through each div, I assume using `$('div').each(...);`. "I am trying to remove the li's with conditon under Ul in multiple div's."

Comment: @Max can you show what the div structure looks like? How many divs are we talking about, with how many ul, and li?

Comment: @kevin: My div's and ul's are dynamic. So definitely I have more than 10 div's and less than 20 div's. li's inside each can be n-numbers